# Hölder's inequality

Tags: real-numbers, riemann-integration

Let p and q be positive real numbers such that $\frac{1}{p}$ + $\frac{1}{q}$ = 1

Here is the Hölder's inequality:

|$\int_a^bfg$ $d\alpha$| $\leq$ {$\int_a^b$ $|f|^p$ $d\alpha$}$^{1/p}$ {$\int_a^b$ $|g|^q$ $d\alpha$}$^{1/q}$

I've a trouble to proof it.

I've tried to proof from  this  inequality:

f(x)g(x) $\leq$ $\frac {f(x)^p}{p}$ + $\frac {g(x)^q}{q}$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it doesn't work. can you explain it further?  @Surb

Comment: Yes it does. See my "answer" below.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

I recall that $\|h\|_{L^r}:=\left(\int_a^b|h|^r\right)^{1/r}$. Taking $$u(x)=\frac{|f(x)|}{\|f\|_{L^p}}\quad \text{and}\quad v(x)=\frac{|g(x)|}{\|g\|_{L^q}},$$ in Young's inequality gives
$$\frac{|f(x)|}{\|f\|_{L^p}}\cdot \frac{|g(x)|}{\|g\|_{L^q}}\leq \frac{1}{p}\cdot \frac{|f(x)|^p}{\|f\|_{L^p}^p}+\frac{1}{q}\cdot \frac{|g(x)|^q}{\|g\|_{L^q}^q}.$$

Integrating both side gives the wished result.

Comment: I don't understand the result of integrating both sides.

Comment: If you integrate both side you'll get $\frac{1}{\|f\|_{L^p}\|g\|_{L^q}}\int_a^b |f(x)||g(x)|\,\mathrm d x\leq 1$, and thus Holder's inequality... @nikadevdariani

Comment: So you say that the integral of the right side is equal of 1? I don't understand . @Surb

Comment: I understand it now. Thank you man